# Add Firefox Developer Edition to Ubuntu's recognized browser

Tags: firefox, browser

I installed the firefox developer edition with umake, added a .desktop file and can start the browser now via clicking the icon on my application menu.

But how do I tell the system (Ubuntu 20.04) that this a browser and it can be used?
This is my desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/home/philipp/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/firefox
Icon=/home/philipp/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Favorite;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp; X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;NewIncognitos;
```

Two examples:

1. Change default browser: Only chrome/regular firefox are displayed as options. Firefox Developer is missing
2. browsersync with `--browser firefox` does work, but with `--browser Firefox Developer Edition` it does not.

My point being, I think Ubuntu hasn't realized I installed another browser. How to achieve that?